# OnActivityResult with embedded Scanner

Tags: java, android, kotlin, barcode-scanner

I have a Android Device with a embedded barcode Scanner.

On pressing the "Scan" button on device, it scans the barcode and the data is displayed in the EditText only if the cursor is on EditText. i.e. The EditText is selected.

I wish to get the scanned result without the EditText selected.

I have tried it with onActivityResult

`@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}`

But I am not getting any results on this.
What can I do ?

I don't want to press a Button to activate the Scanner.

Comment: Which Scanner you are using ?? Provide some overview and code . If this component does not send result back then you can not get it in `onActivityResult` . Barcode scanner is not a native feature of `Android` .

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ZXIng library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), you can launch the scanner as an intent and parse the result.

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){

    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    if (scanResult != null){
        String scanContent = scanResult.getContents();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, scanContent, 5000);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error", 5000);
        toast.show();
    }
};
```

This intent launched through one of the [android lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) methods, such as the   `onCreate()` override.

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

Comment: with the zxing libery i only can call the cam, but i dont want to call the cam. I have a Zebra T200J Device, that has a intigratet Barcodescanner

Comment: [Zebra API Docs](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/7-1/api/) Shows that you can access the scanner through the `BarcodeManager` and the `Scanner`instance methods.